# Facebook SDK Graph API - retrieve family with no profile

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I already have the code to retrieve those members of Facebook identified as Family.  Facebook provides the ability to add family members that do not have a Facebook profile.  I have been unable to find anything within the graph API that allows me to retrieve that information.

Does anyone have information on how to retrieve this information?